# Match the Second Time a Word is Found In Regex

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex

I'm pretty new to Regex and I'm just trying to get my head around it. The string I am trying to search through is this:

```
100 ON 12C 12,41C High Cool OK 0
101 OFF 32C 04,93C Low Dry OK 1
102 ON 07C 08,27C High Dry OK 0
```

What I am trying to do is work out the part to find the part `32C` from the string. If possible, would the code be able to be changed a little each time in order to find the Nth occurrence of the word in the String. If it makes any difference I am going to be using this code in an iPhone application and thus Objective-C.

Comment: Why regex? Why not split the string on newlines, and then split the strings on whitespace? Then (pseudocode) `mystrings[1][2]` would be `32C` (and `mystrings[2][2]` would be `07C` etc.).

Comment: The system that this is being used in is part of a large one that is going to be controlling lots of different types of hardware. For example, it will control music systems, Air Conditioning, TV's etc. it takes a long time to develop drivers for each of these so it is thought this would be an easier way to grab data from String that our returned by the Hardware.

Comment: I fail to see the connection here. I love regexes, but I don't see them as a usable, scalable, maintainable tool in this scenario.

Comment: Basically we are trying to move away from driver development so that users can just be given some code to put into their software and it will find the information they need. It can take up 3 weeks for apple to allow an update for an app to go through and if I user is wanting to control their new TV right now they are going to want it quicker than 3 weeks. So we are trying to find a way to retrieve information programmatically from a returned string. Sorry if this doesnt make sense, its a fairly precise problem we are facing.

Comment: By "the Nth occurrence of the word", do you mean the Nth occurence of the sequence <digit><digit>C (two decimal digits followed by an uppercase C)?

Comment: Yes, But only in this exact way. So for instance not the one of the first line 12.41C.

Comment: The short answer to your question is yes.  It is possible to get an array of matches to your regex.  You can then pick the Nth match from that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is line-oriented and of equal weight (at the same time) biased towards the beginning of the line in the string.

If your engine flavor does grouping, you should be able to specify an occurance quantifier that will get you a single exact answer, without the need to do arrays and such.
In both cases the answer is in capture buffer 1.

examples:

```
$occurance = "2";
---------
/(?:[^\n]*?(\d+C)[^\n]*.*?){$occurance}/s
---------
or
---------
/(?:^.*?(\d+C)[\S\s]*?){$occurance}/m
```

expanded:

```
 /
 (?:
      [^\n]*?
      ( \d+C )
      [^\n]* .*?
 ){2}
 /xs


 /
 (?:
      ^ .*?
      ( \d+C )
      [\S\s]*?
 ){2}
 /xm
```

Comment: How will I know if it supports grouping?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following.  You will have to replace regex_pattern with your regular expression pattern.  In your case, regex_pattern should be something like `@"\\s\\d\\dC"` (a whitespace character (`\\s`) followed by a digit (`\\d`) followed by a digit (`\\d`) followed an upper-case letter `C`.

You may also wish to remove the `NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive` option if you can be sure that the letter C will never be lower case.

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSString *regex_pattern = @"\\s\\d\\dC";

NSRegularExpression *regex =
    [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regex_pattern
    options:(NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive |
         NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators)
    error:&error];

NSArray *arrayOfMatches = [regex matchesInString:myString
                                 options:0
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];

// arrayOfMatches now contains an array of NSRanges;
// now, find and extract the 2nd match as an integer:

if ([arrayOfMatches count] >= 2)  // be sure that there are at least 2 elements in the array
{
    NSRange rangeOfSecondMatch = [arrayOfMatches objectAtIndex:1];  // remember that the array indices start at 0, not 1
    NSString *secondMatchAsString = [myString substringWithRange:
        NSMakeRange(rangeOfSecondMatch.location + 1,  // + 1 to skip over the initial space
                    rangeOfSecondMatch.length - 2)]  // - 2 because we ignore both the initial space and the final "C"

    NSLog(@"secondMatchAsString = %@", secondMatchAsString);

    int temperature = [secondMatchAsString intValue];  // should be 32 for your sample data

    NSLog(@"temperature = %d", temperature);
}
```

Comment: This seems ok. Is there a way to just return the number and not the space or the "C" on either side of it. But still retain only getting this number.

Comment: Yes.  I have expanded the sample code above to show how you might do this.